# Does it making sense to change the maximum entropy condition in MaxEnt or CRFs according to distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-entropy

Assuming English words are in Pareto (Zipf) distribution, when applying a log-linear model, should it still apply Gibbs measure of the maximum entropy condition, or one can change it to the Pareto version?